# Let's customize our tour section!

Tags: discussion, feature-request

> **[The Arduino Stack Exchange Tour Page](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/tour)**

There are a few fields that we can update and change in that page. Here are the things we can change:

1.)

> Arduino Stack Exchange is a question and answer site for developers of open-source hardware and software that is compatible with Arduino. It's built and run by you as part of the Stack Exchange network of Q&A sites. With your help, we're working together to build a library of detailed answers to every question about arduino.

2.)

> How to prevent unicorns from eating daisies

<strike>(We can change this to any question with 25+ votes: [This one](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/564/how-to-trigger-an-alarm-when-toilet-paper-is-low)?)</strike> We only have one question available: [What are the other IDEs for Arduino?](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/40/what-are-the-other-ides-for-arduino)

3.)

> Ask about...
>
> - Specific issues with arduino
> - Real problems or questions that you’ve encountered
>
> Don't ask about...
>
> - Anything not directly related to arduino
> - Questions that are primarily opinion-based
> - Questions with too many possible answers or that would require an extremely long answer

---

There are a few other fields in different locations that I'll talk about later. However, I feel like we should personalize them, making us feel like "not the average beta." **What should we change some of these fields to?**

***Submission Format:***

```
## Update to #[1/2/3]:
> Put Updated Text Here
```

**Please put different fields in different answers.** We can then vote on an individual idea, not a combination of them.

Note: Markup is only available on #1.

Comment: I'd say #1 should be based off our elevator pitch, which we [don't have yet](http://meta.arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/19/what-is-the-elevator-pitch-for-arduino-se).

Answer (score 2):

### Update to #3:

> Ask about...
>
> - Specific issues with Arduino boards, clones, code, and the Arduino IDE
> - Real problems or questions that you’ve encountered
>
> Don't ask about...
>
> - Anything not directly related to Arduino
> - Any question that doesn't require knowledge about the Arduino platform to answer (Try Stack Overflow for general coding questions or
>     Electrical Engineering for general electronics questions)
> - Questions that are primarily opinion-based
> - Questions with too many possible answers or that would require an extremely long answer